# Split $\prod_{i=0}^n (z+i)^{-1}$ into $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i (z+i)^{-1}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I'm trying to find a general formula to split

$$\prod_{i=0}^n (z+i)^{-1} = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i (z+i)^{-1}$$

If $n=1$, we have

$$
\frac{1}{z(z+1)} = \frac{1}{z}+\frac{-1}{z+1}
$$

If $n=2$,

$$
\frac{1}{z(z+1)(z+2)} = \frac{1/2}{z}+\frac{-1}{z+1}+\frac{1/2}{z+2}
$$

If $n=3$,

$$
\frac{1}{z(z+1)(z+2)(z+3)} = \frac{1/6}{z}+\frac{-1/2}{z+1}+\frac{1/2}{z+2} + \frac{-1/6}{z+3}
$$

**Motivation**. I was calculating residues at $z=-m$ of $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\prod_{i=0}^n (z+i)^{-1} $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Heaviside method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method) is
$$\begin{align}\lim_{z\rightarrow-k}(z+k)\prod_{i=0}^n(z+i)^{-1}&=\lim_{z\rightarrow-k}(z+k)\sum_{i=0}^na_i(z+i)^{-1}\\
\frac{(-1)^k}{k!(n-k)!}=a_k\end{align}$$
So how this happened on the left was that
$$\begin{align}\lim_{z\rightarrow-k}(z+k)\prod_{i=0}^n(z+i)^{-1}&=\lim_{z\rightarrow-k}\left[\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(z+i)^{-1}\right]\frac{(z+k)}{(z+k)}\left[\prod_{i=k+1}^{n}(z+i)^{-1}\right]\\
&=\lim_{z\rightarrow-k}\left[\prod_{i=1}^{k}(z+k-i)^{-1}\right]\frac{(z+k)}{(z+k)}\left[\prod_{i=1}^{n-k}(z+k+i)^{-1}\right]\\
&=\left[\prod_{i=1}^{k}(-1)(i)^{-1}\right](1)\left[\prod_{i=1}^{n-k}(i)^{-1}\right]\\
&=\frac{(-1)^k}{k!(n-k)!}\end{align}$$
And on the right we have
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow-k}(z+k)\sum_{i=0}^na_i(z+i)^{-1}=\lim_{z\rightarrow-k}\sum_{i=0}^na_i\frac{(z+k)}{(z+i)}=\sum_{k=0}^na_i\delta_{ik}=a_k$$

Comment: Can you explain how you get it?

Comment: My question is because precisely I don't know how to compute that limit

Comment: Hope the latest edits helped.

Comment: So useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Induction using
\begin{align}
 & \frac{1}{(z+a)(z+a+1)\cdots(z+a+n)} \\
= &  \frac{1/n}{(z+a)\cdots(z+a+n-1)}-\frac{1/n}{(z+a+1)\cdots(z+a+n)}.
\end{align}

Comment: Very good hint, thank you very much.